# Como "Zipar" arquivos ou diretórios no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu já vi na documentação, mas eles falam de maneira muito rasa, e o entendimento não fica bom. Então, alguém pode me explicar de uma forma mais prática de como eu posso zipar arquivos no codeigniter? obrigado.

Link para a documentação: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html

Eu não entendi quase nada, a respeito do processo de zipagem.

Comment: Será interessante você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o link para a documentação, colocando os exemplos de código que ela apresenta aqui, descrevendo o que você não estendeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou tentar explicar o que tem na documentação:

1 - Você deve carregar a lib zip no seu controller.

```
$this->load->library('zip');
```

2 - Você declara os valores que vai utilizar

```
$filepath = 'mydata1.txt'; // Diretório do Arquivo
$data = 'A Data String!'; // Conteúdo do Arquivo
```

3 - Você vai utilizar o método: add_data

```
$this->zip->add_data( $filepath, $data ); // Essa função vai receber 2 parâmetros, o primeiro é o caminho do arquivo e o segundo é o conteúdo desse arquivo.
```

Agora se você já tem o arquivo em algum lugar no seu servidor, você vai utilizar a função abaixo:

```
$this->zip->archive( $path, $archive_filepath ); // Primeiro parâmetro você vai passar o caminho do arquivo, o segundo é opcional caso queira que o zip tenha outro nome ou salvar em outro local.
```